# register / overlay kinect depth profile with webcam / second webcam

Tags: kinect

I want to detect an moving object using Kinect's IR sensor and overlay the depth profile view onto the webcam view from the kinect. Ideally, I would also like to register the kinect pictures with an external webcam.

Any examples on how to get started?

Comment: @Kinected is that a question or an answer?

Comment: Oh should have phrased better, I meant are you using the SDK or OpenNI?

Comment: @Kinected I didn't decide yet which way to go, so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I think you should use opencv and openni for connecting to the kinect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the RGB and depth streams you need to do stereo calibration. Regarding the Kinect itself, it depends on what library/driver you're using as the functionality might be already built for you, allowing you for get the proper RGB value for the same x,y value on the depth image. 
For example:

- with KinectSDK: [MapDepthFrameToColorFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.mapdepthframetocolorframe.aspx)
- with OpenNI : [AlternativeViewPoint](http://openni.org/docs2/tutorial/group__altviewpoint.html)
- with libfreenect: [freenect_pixel_from_depth_map](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openkinect/lGYhvhdJiLs)

Also there are wrapper libraries that simplify things a bit. For example ofxKinect as a [setRegistration()](https://github.com/ofTheo/ofxKinect/blob/master/src/ofxKinect.cpp#L159) method.

If you want to use an external webcam, you would need to calibrate it first. You can find some handy articles on [Niccolas Burrus' wiki](http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration). I also recommend having a look at the [RGBDToolkit](http://www.rgbdtoolkit.com/) project since it does what you're looking for, but with a DSLR camera. The Principle is the same though.

[image: RGBDToolkit]

Here are a few more resources on calibration:

- [OpenCV tutorial](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)
- [utility app](https://vimeo.com/22708033)
- [Depth calibration paper](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~dherrera/kinect/2011-depth_calibration.pdf)